# Как попасть на сервер? Отвалился OpenSSH на VDS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vds

VDS
ISP: hetzner.com.
ОС: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

Настраивал OpenSSH таким образом что бы ограничить пользователей пренадлежащих определенной группе в своем личном пространстве (через Subsytem sftp). Руководствуясь [этим](http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access) рецептом. Создал группу, добавил пользователей (к счастью не всех), определил ChrootDirectory %h. Перезапускаю (при этом сижу от root), ну выдает соответственно что хост закрыл соединение.

```
ssh example.com -l developer
```

На что получаю **ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Connection refused.** Под рутом запретил сидеть на sftp, ftp и ssh.
Ясно что поспешил, не донастроил. Но как бы мне теперь подключится к серверу? Уже по всякому пробовал: rlogin, telnet, sftp. Даже не знаю через что бы еще попробовать. Больше вроде как и не через что. К сожалению доступа к личному кабинету ISP не имею, а человек что им обладает сейчас в отпуске. Хотелось бы справится с ситуацией без обращения в support, а куда копать ума не приложу. Теперь жалею что не поставил webmin.

Comment: а у вас есть там ftp ? заходите через ftp, складываете туда скриптик (php например), который сделает su -c reboot с expect и паролем рута. идете на url этого скрипта и наслаждаетесь ребутом.

---

в следующий раз рестарт ssh делайте в скрине.

Comment: вот тут описано как сделать, если нет expect

http://serverfault.com/a/580813/88690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем путем всенародного самообразования, а именно методом науного тыка и всяческого гугления по теме, ничего так не получилось. Все службы что были задействованы на сервере я прикрыл основательно так что и сам не смог попасть. Пришлось "выуживать" у отпускника пароль от панели хетзнера и исправлять ситуацию в Rescue Mode. Идея со скриптом, высказанная eicto это кстати идея, неприменно ее опробую в ближайшее время. Впредь буду писать подобные вопросы на руткод, просто по привычке опубликовал сюда. Ну и конечно же последую совету и буду использовать консольный мультиплексор screen или аналоги. Спасибо.